# I can not Install WhatsApp In my Lumia 1320 with 8.1 updated

Tags: whatsapp, store

Can not install WhatsApp I get error 805a2029 during download

Comment: Is the time and date set correctly on your phone?

Comment: Have you tried restart the phone?

Comment: May be try doing a soft reset and accessing the store after sometime.